# Pg_dump -s (schema) of tables omits the defaults for columns that use nextval()

Tags: postgresql

After defining the table, the script generated by `PGAdmin via rightclick->SCRIPT->CREATE SCRIPT`, looks like this:

```
-- DROP TABLE public.arr;

CREATE TABLE public.arr
(
    rcdno integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('arr_rcdno_seq'::regclass),
    rcdstate character varying(10) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" DEFAULT 'ACTIVE'::character varying,
    rcdserial integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    msrno integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('arr_msrno_seq'::regclass),
    mobileid character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    edittimestamp timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
    editor character varying(20) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pk_arr PRIMARY KEY (mobileid, msrno, rcdserial)
)
```

After using `>pg_dump -s -U webmaster -W -F p Test > c:\temp\Test.sql`, the table definition in the script `OMITS` the defaults for the `2 original "serial" columns`. This means that the `pg_dump` script doesn't create the table correctly when it is run!

```
--
-- Name: arr; Type: TABLE; Schema: public; Owner: webmaster
--

CREATE TABLE public.arr (
    rcdno integer NOT NULL, -- default missing!
    rcdstate character varying(10) DEFAULT 'ACTIVE'::character varying,
    rcdserial integer DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    msrno integer NOT NULL, -- default missing!
    mobileid character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    edittimestamp timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
    editor character varying(20) NOT NULL
);


ALTER TABLE public.arr OWNER TO webmaster;

--
-- Name: arr_msrno_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: webmaster
--

CREATE SEQUENCE public.arr_msrno_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE public.arr_msrno_seq OWNER TO webmaster;

--
-- Name: arr_msrno_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: webmaster
--

ALTER SEQUENCE public.arr_msrno_seq OWNED BY public.arr.msrno;


--
-- Name: arr_rcdno_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: public; Owner: webmaster
--

CREATE SEQUENCE public.arr_rcdno_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;


ALTER TABLE public.arr_rcdno_seq OWNER TO webmaster;

--
-- Name: arr_rcdno_seq; Type: SEQUENCE OWNED BY; Schema: public; Owner: webmaster
--

ALTER SEQUENCE public.arr_rcdno_seq OWNED BY public.arr.rcdno;
```

EDIT: After the generated script has been run, the statement

```
into public.arr(mobileid, editor)
values
('12345', 'nolaspeaker')
```

generates

`ERROR:  null value in column "rcdno" violates not-null constraint DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, ACTIVE, 0, null, 12345, 2020-08-18 08:54:41.34052, nolaspeaker). SQL state: 23502`

Which indicates that I am correct to assert that the script omits the default values for the rcdno column!

Answer (score 1):

The `ALTER TABLE` statements that set the default values are towards the end of the dump, close to where the `ALTER SEQUENCE ... OWNED BY` are.

If they don't get restored, that might be because there was a problem creating the sequences.

Look at the error messages from the restore, particularly the first ones (later ones are often consequences of the earlier ones).

Comment: Which statements set the defaults for the rcdno and msrno columns, please? All I see are the `owner` statements. No errors are generated!

Comment: Yes, of course the default values are not there. You have to look at the errors to figure out why they were not created.

Comment: There are no errors. I answered my own question below.

Comment: You didn't say that you manually edited the script. So I was on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

The statements that assign the default values to the applicable columns come ***much later*** in the script

```
--
-- Name: arr rcdno; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: webmaster
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.arr ALTER COLUMN rcdno SET DEFAULT nextval('public.arr_rcdno_seq'::regclass);


--
-- Name: arr msrno; Type: DEFAULT; Schema: public; Owner: webmaster
--

ALTER TABLE ONLY public.arr ALTER COLUMN msrno SET DEFAULT nextval('public.arr_msrno_seq'::regclass);
```

So you have to be careful if you cut-and-paste a table definition out of the script!